# How Can I Update a Field in MongoDB While Preserving a Backout Option?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a mongodb collection in a live production environment. I need to update each record in the collection where `"accountInfo.accountNumber"` starts with a leading `0` and remove that `0`, then let an inspection of the data happen, and if necessary back out the changes without impacting existing data.

The query I've used in lower environments to update is:

```js
db.TransactionInfo.aggregate([
  { $match: {"accountInfo.accountNumber": {$regex: '^0.*'}}}, 
  {$set: {"accountInfo.accountNumber": {$ltrim: { input: "$accountInfo.accountNumber", chars: "0"}}}}, 
  {$merge: { into: "TransactionInfo", on: "_id", whenMatched: "replace", whenNotMatched: "discard"}}
])
```

(Any typos are mine, didn't copy/paste but tried to recreate.)

Previously, prior to this query I aggregated all the `_id`'s of records that would be changed into a list, manually copied that list, and in the event a backout was needed I would paste that list into a query that added back the leading `0`.

However, now our DB has several thousand records and the environment will be live as the change is made (though traffic will be slow to nonexistent), so the copy/paste operation is not feasible. Ideally I'm looking for something akin to the 'commit' functionality from a traditional RDBMS.

Because I can't find a way of separating the update from the commit, I'm thinking I could copy the `_id` and `accountInfo.accountNumber` fields to a new collection, let them inspect that collection, then merge back into the original? I'm not sure how to do that - my existing aggregation pipeline copies the whole record...

Comment: So the _"inspection"_ of the update is nonprogrammatic? ... and the decision to keep/backout the update is nonprogrammatic?  If you want to `$merge` partial documents into an _"inspection"_ collection, couldn't you just `$project` the fields you want before the `$merge`?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel [Update with an Aggregation Pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#update-with-an-aggregation-pipeline)